# How to filter bash array values greater than a value

Tags: arrays, bash, filtering

I have an array of indices that was output from a sed command:

```
loc_CPS=$(sed -n $'2s/,/\\\n/gp' ${fileOG} | grep -nx 'CPS' | cut -d: -f1)
```

where ${fileOG} is a .csv file.

Now I need to filter these results for indices that are greater than some value. I've tried initializing a separate empty array to be populated during a loop. For example,

```
max=45
loc_ISTD=()
for ind in ${loc_CPS[@]}; do
    if [[ $ind -gt $max ]]; then
        echo "adding index $ind"
        loc_ISTD+=("$ind")
    fi
done
```

I am unable to get this to work; I've considered how $ind is handled and tried using $((ind)) to ensure it is being treated as an integer (as well as all the condition syntax combinations I could think of). I've also tried using echo to verify each array element is evaluated one at a time. I suspect this problem is related to how values are stored in the original array from the sed command, but I just can't figure out how to force this to work (and I don't know another or better way to build the index array to begin with).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `loc_CPS=$(` is not an array. That's a normal variable.

Comment: `loc_ISTD+=("$ind")` does not modify `loc_ISTD`.  It would append something, if `loc_ISTD` would be an array. It is a pity that bash does not even print a warning here.

Comment: Your dangerous use of `loc_ISTD` in the `for` loop should do what you want, and the `if` condition seems correct, so the CSV might not be what you expect; can you post a few lines of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `loc_CPS` variable is not an array. You would need `loc_CPS=($(some_command ...))` to make it an array. Or `read -ra loc_CPS` to make an array out of an input line. Or `readarray -t loc_CPS` to make an array out of multiple input lines. Also, the use of `sed`, `grep` and `cut` looks complex; most such operations can be done directly in Bash. (Which would be easier to demonstrate if you could provide an example input.)

Here’s some array manipulation:

```bash
max=45
all_values=({0..100})
gt_values=()
le_values=()
for value in "${all_values[@]}"; do
  ((value > max)) && gt_values+=("$value") || le_values+=("$value")
done
echo "${gt_values[@]}"
echo "${le_values[@]}"
```

Things become slightly easier if you declare some variables as integers, because then you can use variable names directly without `$` and quotes:

```bash
declare -i max=45                  # -i optional
declare -ai all_values=({0..100})  # -i optional
declare -ai gt_values=()           # -i needed
declare -ai le_values=()           # -i needed
declare -i value                   # -i optional
for value in "${all_values[@]}"; do
  ((value > max)) && gt_values+=(value) || le_values+=(value)
done
echo "${gt_values[@]}"
echo "${le_values[@]}"
```

You can use indices to access the array:

```
declare -i max=45                  # -i optional
declare -ai all_values=({0..100})  # -i optional
declare -ai gt_values=()           # -i needed
declare -ai le_values=()           # -i needed
declare -i idx                     # -i optional
for idx in "${!all_values[@]}"; do
  ((all_values[idx] > max)) &&
  gt_values+=(all_values[idx]) ||
  le_values+=(all_values[idx])
done
echo "${gt_values[@]}"
echo "${le_values[@]}"
```

And when you are sure that the array is not sparse (which it can be, but it’s not the case here), an arithmetic `for`-loop works too:

```bash
declare -i max=45                  # -i optional
declare -ai all_values=({0..100})  # -i optional
declare -ai gt_values=()           # -i needed
declare -ai le_values=()           # -i needed
declare -i idx                     # -i optional
for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#all_values[@]}; ++idx)); do
  ((all_values[idx] > max)) &&
  gt_values+=(all_values[idx]) ||
  le_values+=(all_values[idx])
done
echo "${gt_values[@]}"
echo "${le_values[@]}"
```